# app crashes on changing min sdk version and target version

Tags: android, xml, performance, android-layout, android-view

I have this app working on my test phone ,but i got an parsing package error in samsung phone.

On further googling gave me the solution to change the sdk version to 1.I changed the min sdk version to 1 (initially 13) and android target to 1(initially 13), and my app is crashing ,can some one help me on this .

This is the eclipse logcat

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mystictreegames.pagecurl/com.mystictreegames.pagecurl.StandaloneExample}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.mystictreegames.pagecurl.PageCurlView
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.mystictreegames.pagecurl.PageCurlView
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at com.mystictreegames.pagecurl.StandaloneExample.onCreate(StandaloneExample.java:22)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   ... 11 more
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   ... 22 more
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:554)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at com.mystictreegames.pagecurl.PageCurlView.init(PageCurlView.java:419)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   at com.mystictreegames.pagecurl.PageCurlView.<init>(PageCurlView.java:208)
 E/AndroidRuntime(10146):   ... 25 more
```

Comment: Did you remove the code that wasn't available in v.1?

Comment: Error inflating `com.mystictreegames.pagecurl.PageCurlView`. on line number 6. Check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set your target SDK version to 1. Set it to your actual target: the level where you have developed and tested your app.

When you set your target to less than 4, you'll get a compatibility mode enabled which scales your resources automatically, assuming everything is MDPI ([reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#DONUT)). This automatic scaling is the likely cause for the exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()`.